# Call Service Only For One Time in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I'm calling a get service in `componentWillMount()`. Service response me a object in the form of JSON I which mentioned below. But I need the values of service objects into my variables/objects so I made a loop when I'm getting the data from service and it works fine but the issue is that it takes too much time to pass the data into my objects/variables. It take at least 45 to 50 seconds to pass the service data into my objects. If I removed the loop so service respond me perfectly but I need the values of service into my objects. Please provide me the best solution for it. Thanks

Service JSON Response

```
{
    "Capital": 0,
    "Code": "BOL",
    "Code2": "",
    "Continent": "",
    "GNP": 0,
    "Name": "Bolivia",
}
```

I need the Code into key variable and Name into label variable

```
axios.get('http://apiurl.com/api/user/GetCountries')
            .then((response) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    var joined = this.state.countriesModel.concat({ key: response.data[i].Code, label: response.data[i].Name });
                    this.setState({ countriesModel: joined });
                }
                this.hideLoader();
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });
```

Comment: I think the issue is you are using `setState` in for loop. Instead generate the data and use it once.

Comment: can you show me any example?

Comment: something like (using map instead for lop): `var joined = response.data.map(function(obj){ return {key: obj.Code, label: obj.Name}}); this.setState({ countriesModel: joined });`

Comment: @iskorum it took same time to load.

Comment: Hmm. Then maybe this is the issue: https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html

Comment: What about your service response time? did you test it? and it returns an Array of objects or a single object?

Comment: Thanks all the issue has been solved by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made array outside state and it works perfectly. `setState` is taking too much time to set the data.

```
countiesOptions = [];
componentDidMount(){
    var joined = this.countiesOptions.concat({ key: response.data[i].Code, label: response.data[i].Name });
    this.countiesOptions = joined;
}
```